# Apple Mach-O Linker error : Undefined symbols for architecture i386 for boost libraries

Tags: macos

I am building an command line application on OS X that uses boost library( currently i am using version 1.48 ). It is a Xcode project. In the Build settings, for the "C++ Standard Libray" field i am using `libstd++` ( GNU c++ standard library ). But i want to use the latest `libc++` ( LLVM C++ standard library ). When i change to `libc++`, i get linker error for the boost libraries.
Error is that it is not able to find the symbols.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386
"boost::filesystem::path_traits::dispatch(boost::filesystem::directory_entry    const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&)", referenced from:
boost::enable_if<boost::filesystem::path_traits::is_pathable<boost::decay<boost::filesystem::directory_entry>::type>, boost::filesystem::path&>::type boost::filesystem::path::operator=<boost::filesystem::directory_entry>(boost::filesystem::directory_entry const&) in MyCode.o
```

There are many such errors, i am pasting only one. All the rest are similar.

I tried downloading, building and installing the latest boost library with toolset as clang using this http://hnrkptrsn.github.io/2013/02/26/c11-and-boost-setup-guide/

But the problem still persists. Is there any solution for this problem ?

Comment: Well as you might realise, if you use `libc++` in the executable then all compiled libraries must use that runtime library too.  I always use Macports, which makes installing packages a doddle and I *believe* that uses `libc++` for boost. I would give that a try.

Comment: @trojanfoe Are you suggesting that I install the boost library using the Macports ? Something like `port install boost` ?

Comment: Yes, that is how I would install boost.